# Stored procedure runs correctly only sometimes

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, lazarus

My problem is: I have a stored procedure that only sometimes runs correctly, sometimes it does not run at all and sometimes partially (some rows where inserted in the table bot not all). I use lazarus 2.0.6 on Win10 64bit and a `TODBCConnection` to connect to SQL Server 2012.

The stored procedure itself is correct, in SQL Server Management Studio, it runs without problems. The stored procedure writes records into 4 different tables; depending on the parameters approximately 1-400 records per table.

The code:

```
con:TODBCConnection;
tra:TSQLTransaction;
qry:TSQLQuery;

con:=TODBCConnection.Create(nil);
tra:=TSQLTransaction.Create(nil);
qry:=TSQLQuery.Create(nil);

tra.DataBase:=con;
qry.DataBase:=con;
qry.Transaction:=tra;

con.Params.Clear;
con.Params.Add('DRIVER=SQL Server');
con.Params.Add('SERVER=xxxxx');
con.Params.Add('DATABASE='+DATENBANK_NAME);
con.Params.Add('Trusted_Connection=Yes');
con.Params.Add('AUTOCOMMIT=1');
con.Open; 

// call the procedure
sql:='EXEC dm.createStorage2 @St_Geraet='Q', @St_Bezeichnung='Q-Freezer -80', @St_Temperatur=-80, @St_Raum='Keller', @St_Gebaeude='ABC', 
@St_AnzFaecher=2, @St_AnzTuermeProFach=5, @St_MoeglicheSchubladenkombinationenProTurm='4,3', @St_MoeglicheBoxenkombinationenProSchublade='3,4', 
@St_MoeglicheBoxKapazitaeten='16,25,100', @schubladenProTurm=4, @boxenProSchublade=3, @boxkapazitaet=16;';

qry.SQL.Text:=sql;
qry.ExecSQL;

// alternatively, this will also not work:
// con.ExecuteDirect(sql);

con.Close();
qry.Free;
tra.Free;
con.Free;
```

If I set a breakpoint at `qry.ExecSQL;` and step over it - it works ?!

It seems that it doesn't wait for `qry.ExecSQL;` to finish and frees the resources directly afterwards. What can I do to tell the code to wait until `qry.ExecSQL;` is finished?

Edit: the problem seems to be that `qry.ExecSQL;` runs asynchronous instead of synchronous as it should be. How can I tell this call to run synchronous?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would take out the semicolon in `@boxkapazitaet=16;`, but i doubt if that has anything to do with your problem....

Comment: Why use TODBC?, see point 4 of [this](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Database_Overview#Lazarus_and_MSSQL.2FSybase) , did you try with `mssqlconn` ?

Comment: @Luuk: for msssqlcon i need special drivers there not shipped with lazuarus. the only source for this is a ond website "freetds" on which you must self compile the drivers to a dll. the driver source is linux based quellcode and the links dead.

Comment: Can you add a check to catch the output parameter of this stored procedure? (see "Output parameters of stored procedures" on this [page](https://wiki.freepascal.org/mssqlconn). After this is should be possible to check if the stored procedure ran correctly, or transaction was rolled back because of something...

Comment: @Luuk: as i wrote, i cant use mssqlconn. the stored procedure returns nothing, because odbc-conns can´t read return values of stored procedures (lazarus odbc). it´s a limitation. the only thing i would to know is how can i tell TODBCConnection or TSQLQuery tu run synchronous insteed of asynchronous. i searched but not found everything.

Comment: Please edit your q to show the actual, exact, code to the right of `sql :=`.  It is clearly **not** as you have shown it, because of the single-quotes being syntactically incorrect.  Please also add the DDL Sql for your dm.createStorage2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have it figured out: it´s a bug in sqldb.pas, in combination with odbc he can´t detect when a stored procedure is finished. so the programm immediatly steps to the next command, which in my case was the freeing of the database-instance -with the result that the sql-command was aborted.
using now the "zeos" library (https://zeoslib.sourceforge.io) and it works like a charm.

```
uses
Classes, SysUtils, ZConnection, ZDataset;

...

con:=TZConnection.Create(nil);
qry:=TZQuery.Create(nil);

qry.Connection:=con;

con.Protocol:='ado';
con.Database:='DRIVER=SQL Server;Trusted_Connection=Yes;SERVER=xxxx;DATABASE='+DATENBANK_NAME;
con.Connected:=true;
```

the rest is identical to the old code, with one excaption:
`con.close();` becomes `con.connected:=false;`